# Recording of personal property contribution to S-Corp in QuickBooks

Tags: united-states, small-business, accounting, s-corporation, quickbooks

I began an S-Corp, and I contributed a truck, computers, and furniture. How do I record these items in QuickBooks? What accounts do I use?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create Journal Entries that debit asset accounts that are associated with these items and credit an [Open Balance Equity](http://www.accountingtools.com/questions-and-answers/opening-balance-equity.html) account.

The value of these contributions would have to be worked out with an accountant, as it depends on [the lesser of the adjusted basis vs. the fair market value](https://www.thebalance.com/donating-property-to-an-s-corporation-3193484), as you then depreciate the amounts over time to take the depreciation as a business expense, and it adjusts your basis in the company (to calculate capital gains/losses when you sell).

If there were multiple partners, or your accountant wants it this way, you could then debit open balance equity and credit the owner's contribution to a capital account in your name that represents your basis when you sell.

From a pure accounting perspective, if the Open Balance Equity account would zero out, you could just skip it and directly credit the capital accounts, but I prefer the Open Balance Equity as it helps know the percentages of initial equity which may influence partner ownership percentages and identify anyone who needs to contribute more to the partnership.